# How to trim video in android?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I know the same question has been asked so many times, but I am not able to solve my issue.

Hi, I tried FFmpeg command for trimming video & it works quite good. I want to trim a video & it works, but the only problem I have is that it takes too much time to trim the file.A 24MB video file takes around 3 minutes to trim 2.30 minutes.Is there any way I can reduce this time.
I have tried following command for trimming video. i.e.

```
ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/DCIM/Besharam.mp4 -ss 00:00:05 -to 00:02:35 -async 1 -strict -2 /sdcard/sai/cut.mp4
```

and

```
ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/DCIM/Besharam.mp4 -ss 00:00:05 -to 00:02:35 -async 1 -strict -2 -s 640x360 -r 15 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 2097152 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -b 2097152 -ar 22050 /sdcard/sai/cut.mp4
```

Comment: you are basically re-encoding the entire video, which is naturally a slow process. quicker method would be to figure out where in the bytestream your cut points are and simply trim the bytes before/after.

Comment: @Marc B2 can you share any source code or solution for it.

Comment: you can just copy stream without reencoding instead of -vcodec mpeg4 use -vcodec copy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy the codecs of your input file by providing the `-c copy` option. Furthermore seeking before specifying the input file [is said](https://superuser.com/a/141343/401689) to be faster but less accurate.

After implementing these 2 changes your command would look like:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:05 -i /sdcard/DCIM/Besharam.mp4 -to 00:02:35 -async 1 -strict -2 -c copy /sdcard/sai/cut.mp4
```

Comment: I want to compress a video to lower size & it works, but the only problem I have is that it takes too much time to compress the file. Can you have any solution for its like trimming video? I have used following the command for it.

ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/DCIM/Besharam.mp4 -strict experimental -s 640x360 -r 25 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 1000k -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Use this library for video trimming [Android-video-trimmer](https://github.com/a914-gowtham/Android-video-trimmer)

Comment: this library has a lot of issues, last issue which i can't solve so far is ```Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider```